# Swift queue of anonymous functions

Tags: ios, swift, queue, anonymous-function

I am looking for the Swift equivalent of a queueing pattern/structure that will allow me to add anonymous methods to a queue and then execute them by fetching/popping them from the list (Java sample below)

This pattern is prevalent in most languages but I cannot seem to find how to do this?

```
interface IQueueMethod {
    void invoke();
}


LinkedList<IQueueMethod> list = new LinkedList<IQueueMethod>();
// add method
list.add(() -> {
...some logic here
});
// Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this queue, and execute it
list.poll().invoke();
```

Comment: `Array<() -> Void>`?

Comment: Are you looking for `(NS)Operations` & `(NS)OperationQueue` maybe? Else, an array of closure could be a way.

Comment: @user28434, that will do thanks. I can implement queue structures myself. I think I struggled to find this because in the Swift/IOS world it seems this is referred to more as a "closure" and not an anonymous function